# How to assign view block to dynamic taxonomy term page for CCK entries

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7, taxonomy, drupal-theming

http://localhost/rkk/work-type/non-profit

I created a vocabulary and terms under for work-type. and I created some posts...

Then I created a View Block to list my entries, and assigned to a page... everything fine so far.

I display the work-type at entry details page. and I have a link "click to see other non-profit(assigned work type) works". When I click this link, it lists entries assigned to that particular work-type. thats fine, but it displays title/body/readmorelink :/ I need custom view for this page, like I did View Block for listing all posts...

Can I assign custom created View Block to this taxonomy entry list page? the url changes according to work-type, so how do I assign view to changing-url :/

Appreciate helps!! thanks a lot!

---

**UPDATE FOR MORE INFO:**

I have a vocabulary (work type), and terms under (corporate, non-profit, etc...)

I have a CCK for "work", and as a field I have select terms of work-type vocabulary.

I have a Custom Views Block to display works in a page (thumb, title, desc, link, etc.).

When I click a work, it goes to particular Work entry details page, I place a link in there "click to see other -term (corporate)- works", etc.

When I click this link, it displays the Work Entries under that particular term. it works fine. but it displays as default look (shown as below), but I need this page same as main works page list (thumb, title, desc, link, etc.) I already have a View for this, but how can assign this View to this dynamic url taxonomy page? I found the module http://drupal.org/project/tvi , but cant make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be simpler to overwrite term pages with a view, there's already a pre-configured view for this : taxonomy_term (wich is disabled by default)

Comment: oh thanks! that's a good idea :) but I have more than 1 taxonomy, and all have different fields with different display... how can I assign the taxonomy_term for this particular vocabulary?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you mean. Update your question to explain your vocabulary structure, it should help.